# Why does the user get the role when a different person other than the user mentioned reacted to the check mark?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering in my code I specifically want the user who was "offered" to get the role when they react to the "✅" But instead it adds the role to the user if a different person adds the check mark here is my code:

```py
import discord
import os
import replit
import asyncio
import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("ready!")
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="over VRFL"))
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('<:WAS:768298406744817725> offer'):
    emoji1 = '✅'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    member = message.mentions[0]
    role = get(message.guild.roles, name= 'Washington Football Team')
    await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has **30 Minutes** to Accept **Minnesota Vikings** <:Vikings:766499160731287572> offer ⏱')
    
    async def check(reaction, user):
      return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅' and reaction.message == message
    try:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=1800, check=check)
      await member.add_roles(role)
      await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has Accepted the **Washington Football Team** <:WAS:768298406744817725> offer')
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Did not Accept the **Washington Football Team** <:WAS:768298406744817725> offer in the 30 Minutes given')
    else:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this:
`member = message.author`
instead of
`member = message.mentions[0]`

Let me know please if it doesn't work.

Cheers.